# Eclipse - code proposals not working properly

Tags: java, eclipse, intellisense

I'm working on a JavaFX app but somehow the code proposals doesn't work correctly. For example here:

[image]

It doesn't show any proposals but it recognizes the class.

[image]

Any ideas why?